# JPlayer live-stream on android

Tags: html, audio, jplayer

I'm trying to use jPlayer as live-stream player ([source](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-08/)) on mobile devices (Android).
But it doesn't work!
Also I tried to use native html5 audio with live-radio URL (e.g. [Jazz from radionomy](http://listen.radionomy.com/abc-jazz)) but is also doesn't work on my android 4.1!

Can you help me? Show me a sample, how to use audio live-stream (e.g. live radio) on Android browser?

Thank you very much!